# D3heatmap not found for R Version 4.0

Tags: r

I'm trying to install an old package I had in RStudio for an old version of RStudio but I get the following:

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘d3heatmap’ is not available (for R version 4.0.0)

I'm trying to install d3heatmap but ever since I upgraded to 4.0, I can't install it. I'm thinking I have to install an old version of RStudio. But I want to verify if d3heatmap is still available and what versions it still works for but I can't find any information on it.

Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: It's been removed from CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/d3heatmap/index.html, You can go here and download the latest version and install it locally: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/d3heatmap/

Comment: Thanks Phil! That worked. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

you can downloaded the zip file here (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/d3heatmap/)

and run this code in Rstudio

```
install.packages("d3heatmap_0.6.1.2.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
```